# How do I make center-aligned text on the right side of a picture (Apache POI docx)

Tags: java, apache-poi

This is the result I want to get:
[image]

Things I've tried:

1. Adding another `XWPFRun` to the `XWPFParagraph` the picture is in, but that treats the picture as a character in the paragraph and it doesn't work ([example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twfNt.png));
2. Putting the picture and the text in two different cells of a table, but I couldn't find a way to make the table borders not visible;
3. Creating two separate `XWPFParagraph`s, but that just puts the text below the picture;

I also thought it could be done by making a two-column paragraph then putting the picture in one column, and the text in the second column. But I couldn't find a way to make a two-column paragraph with Apache POI.

Here's the code I used for two `XWPFRun`s in a `XWPFParagraph` which doesn't give me the result I want:

```
        XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument();
        XWPFHeader header = doc.createHeader(HeaderFooterType.DEFAULT);
        XWPFParagraph headerParagraph = header.createParagraph();
        XWPFRun pictureRun = headerParagraph.createRun();
        String imgFile = "D:\\picture.jpg";
        
        try (FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(imgFile)) {
            pictureRun.addPicture(is,
                    Document.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG,    
                    imgFile,
                    Units.pixelToEMU(297),
                    Units.pixelToEMU(124)); 
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        XWPFRun headerTextRun = headerParagraph.insertNewRun(1);
        headerTextRun.setText("Some text");

        try (FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("D:\\test.docx")) {
            doc.write(out);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Is there some way I can do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for this will be using a table. To remove the borders current `apache poi` [XWPFTable](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTable.html) provides `removeBorders` method.

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.util.Units;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordTablePIctureAndTextNoBorders {
    
 static final int TWIPS_PER_INCH = 1440; //measurement unit for table cell width and tab stop pos is twips (twentieth of an inch point);

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("Image on the left and text on the right");

  //create table
  XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
  
  //remove all table borders
  table.removeBorders();
  
  //set table width 6 inches
  table.setWidth(6 * TWIPS_PER_INCH);
  
  //create CTTblGrid for this table with widths of the 2 columns. 
  //necessary for Libreoffice/Openoffice to accept the column widths.
  //first column = 3 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().addNewTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(3 * TWIPS_PER_INCH));
  //second column = 3 inches width
  table.getCTTbl().getTblGrid().addNewGridCol().setW(BigInteger.valueOf(3 * TWIPS_PER_INCH));
  
  //get or create first row
  XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.getRow(0); if (tableRow == null) tableRow = table.createRow();
  //get or create first cell
  XWPFTableCell cell = tableRow.getCell(0); if (cell == null) cell = tableRow.addNewTableCell();
  //set cell vertical align
  cell.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
  //set width for first column
  cell.setWidth("50%");

  //get or add first paragraph in first cell
  paragraph = cell.getParagraphArray(0); if (paragraph == null) paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
  //create run in paragraph having picture
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.addPicture(new FileInputStream("./Koala.png"), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, "Koala.png", Units.toEMU(200), Units.toEMU(150));
  
  //get or create econd cell
  cell = tableRow.getCell(1); if (cell == null) cell = tableRow.addNewTableCell();
  cell.setWidth("50%");
  cell.setVerticalAlignment(XWPFTableCell.XWPFVertAlign.CENTER);
  
  //get or add first paragraph in second cell
  paragraph = cell.getParagraphArray(0); if (paragraph == null) paragraph = cell.addParagraph();
  paragraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor");
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam");
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat,"); 
  run = paragraph.createRun();
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("sed diam voluptua.");
 
  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTablePIctureAndTextNoBorders.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Produces:

[image]